# Bridged Network - Routing to primary gateway

Tags: networking, dd-wrt, bridge, windows-networking

I have a unique setup that I would like to make work rather than physically move my devices. I'm sure this is simple, but i've done too many trial and errors to wrap my head around the proper resolution that "should" work.

1. I have a wireless router (192.168.1.1) beaming "SSID-5" and "SSID" from ISP modem.
2. In another area, I have a computer with 2 network adapters (Ethernet + Wireless).
3. I have two NAS' (NAS1 = 192.168.1.18 and NAS2 = 192.168.1.118) connected to a Linksys Switch WRT160N (DD-WRT configured to act as a simple switch or so i think - 192.168.1.111).

I would like to make the NAS' (#3) be available on the network (#1), by connecting to the Ethernet NIC (#2). A bridged-connection between Ethernet + Wireless (#2) would make the NAS' available.

Configuring the bridged-connection is what I have issues with.
There are two main recurring problems that keeps this bridge from working.

1. The bridge doesn't automatically work. I must set a static IP on the bridge and also add a static IP on the Ethernet before adding it to the bridge. Sometimes this will work for a day before stopping. What is the best way to configure this without fail?
2. If the bridge does work, the internet connection on #2 becomes dreadfully slow. I suspect it takes time to find the valid gateway + DNS. Perhaps the switch (#3) needs a certain config? Or the computer (#2) needs a persistent route?

I know troubleshooting my specific setup would be difficult especially not knowing how the switch (#3) is exactly configured. But i'm wondering... if you were to make this setup work, what would you check? and is there any route or dd-wrt setting i should be checking?